# Stack trace in New Relic shows 99% of time in Rails::Rack::Logger#call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I've been working on improving performance of a high throughput endpoint and I've reduced all the sql calls to just a few ms but the average response time is still > 150ms.

New Relic highlights really poor performing stack traces and in all of those examples I see:

Rails::Rack::Logger#call taking up 99% of the time (over 2 seconds).  What is causing these hangups? There is definitely no logging happening and these entries don't show up on the average call to the endpoint?

Comment: New Relic's transaction traces have a "Trace Details" tab that should show you where in the stack the `Logger` call is being made, which will help pinpoint the problem. If your `Logger` calls are taking 2 full seconds to complete then I would guess that you are logging synchronously to a remote TCP endpoint from within Rails. Check your `config.logger` settings in `config/application.rb` and `config/environments/*.rb` and post them here for more help.

Comment: Yeah that seems like a reasonable guess...however, the weird part is there is definitely no logging happening in the endpoint I'm viewing the trace of.

Comment: It's probably a gem that you have installed, then.

Comment: turns out it was just the default logging settings in rails.. I switched to this gem for logging: https://github.com/gshaw/concise_logging which cleans up production logs and all of the Rails::Rack::Logger entries in new relic have gone away

Comment: Excellent! Also consider [lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) for Rails logging.

Comment: I'm also seeing this on Rails v4.1. Fingers crossed upgrading to v4.2 will fix this.